# How to upload a python file with Kivy to iPhone for free?

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I am creating a simple Kivy app in python, but I can't figure out how to upload the .py as app to my iPhone for free.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

according to kivy documentation:

> In order to submit any application to the iTunes store, you will need an iOS Developer License. For testing, you can use a physical device or the XCode iOS emulator.

I suggest using a cheap android phone to test out your application. You will need to package your application for Android. In order to do this, you will need to use Linux.